# PyCharm favorites lists

Tags: pycharm

I am confused about PyCharm's feature "[Favorites Lists](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/2016.2/managing-your-project-favorites.html)".  I thought it would be a way to manage groups of projects and switch from one group to another, but I may have misunderstood.  (BTW, I love that when I have a group of projects opened in the editor, VCS pull/push applies to all of them).

Anyway, I can see how to add/modify a favorite list, and how to create/delete  one.

But how do I switch to the projects that are in a favorites list?  How come when I restart pycharm, I don't get a choice between the various lists?

More generally, what is the purpose of "favorites lists" if not to switch focus to the projects therein?